# Why does script execution time increase over time when using file.write()?

Tags: python

I'm trying python for the first time.  I wrote this script below:

```
# Importing modules
import time

buffersize = 10000
f = open(time.strftime("%M-%S.raw", time.gmtime()),"w")

try:
  while True:
    start = time.time()
    for x in xrange(0,buffersize):
      blah = " "
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    f.write(str(elapsed)+"\r\n")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  f.close()
```

When I inspect the raw file after running this script, I noticed that the `elapsed` variable increases as the script runs on.  Here's an example sequence of values:

```
4.79221343994e-05
0.916402101517
0.980934858322
1.05616092682
1.15645098686
1.30846095085
1.54870700836
1.87860512733
2.74350309372
4.1800429821
4.71334385872
5.24211788177
5.8994808197
```

I was expecting the script to only generate a list of values that reflect a few hundred milliseconds, give or take 100 milliseconds, instead of an ascending list of values.

Is this because the file object is storing data in memory which slows down the script over time?  I'm supposed to flush the memory in some way to reduce execution time?  Or am I misunderstanding something?

NOTE:
The reason I'm trying to time the for loop is because in another script of mine, I actually have the line `blah = " "` replaced by some code that tries
to fetch values from my MCP3008 chip on a raspberry pi.  The list of ascending values wasn't what I expected.  So I started trimming down my code to what you see above to see what's going on.

Comment: You aren't timing the `write` at all, you're timing the loop that precedes it. You generate a new `start` time after the write completed, so the difference between `start` and `elapsed` doesn't include the write at all.

Comment: That said, if I squint a bit, and pretend that CPython didn't optimize `" "` to be a singleton, I'd think you were testing the performance of the garbage collector, nothing to do with I/O.

Comment: Also, `time.time()` is looking at the wall-clock, so if something else is using time on your system (or the C library is stopping to flush buffers to disk or who-knows-what-else is happening) it gets confused with the performance of the program you're intentionally running. See https://www.pythoncentral.io/measure-time-in-python-time-time-vs-time-clock/, and consider using the Python `timeit` module for microbenchmarking instead of trying to roll it yourself. `timeit` knows how to use the most accurate available clock, and disables garbage collection to avoid impact on your results.

Comment: Thanks Charles, you are correct that I'm trying to time the for loop.  It's because in the for loop, I'm actually trying to log how long it takes to read 10000 analog values from my MCP3008 chip connected to a raspberry pi.  But the logs showing the ascending values of elapsed time didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Short form is that this is a fact-intensive investigation, with no easy generic-to-all-Python-runtimes answer. Heck, on embedded hardware, it's possible to overheat and cause the clock to throttle back.

Comment: ...that said, you might also print `start` as well as the current `time.time()`, just as a sanity check. If that *weren't* being updated in the real implementation, it's an easy answer.

Comment: That is so weird..I restarted my raspberry pi, and now I'm seeing a reasonable series of 0.005. And when I replace `blah = " "` with the code that reads values from MCP3008, I'm also getting sensible numbers now....